# ETA using Google Maps API On Android / IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a GPS tracking application for Android / IOS. I would like my users to get an ETA before the tracked person reach it's destination. Based on licensing information, it seems that the native map control does not impose usage limits, but the distance matrix API does (2500 requests per day) if I undestand well as it is not part of the native API per say. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#Limits

Is the limit applied even if it is used on a mobile phone? Is there a way to get this information using the native API to avoid getting the limit (ex: calling a web service)? Is there any other ways I could get the information? I heard of the MapQuest API, but I would need to use them all the way with OpenStreetMap... I would expect my ETA to be refreshed every 30 seconds I guess?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is the limit applied even if it is used on a mobile phone?

Yes, the limit still applys since you are using the API.

> Is there a way to get this information using the native API to avoid
>   getting the limit (ex: calling a web service)?

For iOS, you can use [URL Scheme.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#directions) It looks like there are no quota limits. Or for Web Service, you can use [Javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: The URL Scheme will start the Google App application, not give me the data. The Javascript API is exactly the one that is limited...

Comment: The Javascript Direction service doesn't have 2,500 quota limit. According to the developer console the quota has 1,000,000 limit

Comment: 1,000,000 is the maximum billable. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage